# Best practice for overriding __getattr__ in new-style classes

Tags: python

I'd like to process access on undefined class attributes and default to normal behavior if the item is not in a predefined global valid set. Normally I would do something like this:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __getattr__(self, item):
        if item in valid_set:
            #some logic here
            return None
        # The following will not work
        return super(Foo, self).__getattr__(item)
```

But `super(Foo, self).__getattr__(item)` is not valid. What should be the default return here?

Comment: It depends on your object semantics you can return `None` or raise the exception if it's suitable. As far as I know there is no default behaviour here.

Comment: just raise an `AttributeError`. that's the default behaviour. `__getattr__` is called when the property you're trying to access doesn't exist in the object